# How to limit string characters when rendered in MeteorJS

Tags: jquery, string, meteor

Hi I have a template like this:

```
<template name="list">
{{# each list}}
    <a class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 list-item" href="/{{category}}/{{_id}}">
        <div class="list-item-inner">
            <img class="col-md-12 img-responsive" src="#" />
            <div class="col-md-12 list-title">
                {{vTitle}}
            </div>
            <div class="min">
                <span>00:00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

How can i limmit the {{vTitle}} to a certain amount of characters, say to 10 characters ?
I'm asking for something that has not to do with Templete.*.rendered and after that editing again with jquery or something.

Is there something I suppose like : {{vTitle.limitCharacters(10)}} or some method that MeteorJs, blaze offers.

Tried this: 
{{vTitle.substring(0,10)}}

I don't know how blaze works, I just gave it a shot.

My solution, I added a helper shortTitle like the example below then changet the {{vTitle}} in the template with {{shortTitle}} :

```
Template.list.helpers({
    list : function() {
        return Collection.find();
    },
    shortTitle: function() {
        return this.vTitle.substr(0,15)+'...';
    }
});
```

Special thanks to @David Weldon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I have done this in our projects. Choose your own adventure:

### css

You can do truncation with pure css using [this trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/):

```css
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Just apply the `truncate` class to your title and it will truncate at the parent div's width. The upside is that no javascript is required, but the downsides are that it only works on modern browsers and you can't specify a precise number of characters.

### underscore.string

If you want to be more precise at the expense of writing more helper code, you can use a library like [underscore.string](https://atmospherejs.com/wizonesolutions/underscore-string) which contains the `truncate` and `prune` methods. `prune` is especially nice when you want to truncate only whole words.

```js
Template.list.helpers({
  shortTitle: function() {
    return _.str.prune(this.vTitle, 10);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Dacid Weldon The .truncate class does not work on my example especially the  {white-space: nowrap;}

Tried that helper just added it like you wrote it. It does not work.

Comment: For the css solution, you probably need to set the width as they do in the example link I provided. Without the width, it will be limited by the width of the parent which may not be what you want. As for the js, try this in your console: `_.str.prune('this is a very long string', 10);`. It should return `"this is a..."`. If it does, then something else is wrong with your helper or template (did you make sure to use `shortTitle` in the html?). If it does not, then the package was not added.

Comment: I tried and sorry no the _.str.prune does not work. But I got allot help from you thank you. My solution to _.str.prune is this: return this.vTitle.substr(0,15)+'...';